# probs with screen refresh after rotation

Tags: android, rotation, refresh

I have a kind of file browser. The user can run some file operations and when they're finished, the screen will be refreshed so the user can see the actual state of the files. BUT: If the user rotates his device during the operation he sees a fully new instance of the application. So the old instance is refreshed after the operation is finished but not that one the user looks at. How is it possible to resolve this problem? How can I make the currently shown app instance refresh?

Comment: Did you try putting android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" tag in your Activity in Manifest.xml file? Sorry if this is irrelevant, but this is what I could understand from your question.

Comment: YES!!! I knew there's something easy and useful for that problem! :)) Thank's a lot! This is the solution! Things should be always easy like this :)))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity restart on rotation Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)